# Removing latency of atomic clock API call

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to sync the universal clock with the device clock in Flutter. For the universal time, I am calling public API with some latency. I want to remove that latency so that I know what is the time of device at given universal time instance.

Comment: How much is the latency?

Comment: for complete API  call its dynamic. Sometimes 4 sec sometimes 2sec sometimes even in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Is Android a real time OS?
No, Android is not a Real Time Operating System. An OS should be time deterministic and there by being predictable to become RTOS.